# Find $A$ and $B$ such that $A⊈B$ and $B⊈A$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification, proof-writing, order-theory

I need to prove that the subset relation “$⊆$” on all subsets of $\mathbb Z$ is not a total order and I'm going to do this by finding $A$ and $B$ such that $A⊈B$ and $B⊈A$?

Is there a simple solution for this?

Comment: Almost any two subsets…

Comment: -1 because OP didnt give a single thought to this

Comment: Your title does not render correctly on my Android. I see a box where there's probably supposed to be a containment symbol. There are LaTeX commands for that so you don't have to use special characters.

Comment: ...granted, those wouldn't render correctly either, but at least the command would be there and could be interpreted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. For instance
$$
A = \{1\}, B = \{2\}\\
A = \text{All the negative integers},B = \text{All the positive integers}\\
A = \{2n \mid n \in \Bbb Z\}, B = \{2n+1\mid n \in \Bbb Z\}\\
A = \Bbb Z \setminus \{1\}, B = \Bbb Z \setminus \{2\}\\
A = \{5n \mid n \in \Bbb Z\}, B = \{3n \mid n \in \Bbb Z\}
$$

Answer (score 1):

Any two subsets with a non-empty symmetric difference ($A \setminus B) \cup (B \setminus A$) satisfy your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. For instance,

$A=n\mathbb{Z}$ and $B=m\mathbb{Z}$, with $gcd(m,n)=1.$

Answer (score 0):

Example of subsets can be chosen from the smaller sets $\{1,2,\ldots 30\}$.
Let $A$ be the set of dates in a calendar month when Alice is going to have pizza for dinner, and let $B$ be the set of dates Bob is going to have pizza.

Now $A\subset B$ means, on all the dates Bob had pizza Alice had it too.

Now you can draw up a pizza eating schedule for both of them meeting the condition in your question.